# Want to remove a specific url from Magento sitemap.xml?

Tags: magento-1.9, xml, sitemaps

Want to remove a specific url from default magento sitemap.xml

I don't want this url http://www.globekart.com/coupon-partners.html in the sitemap http://www.globekart.com/sitemap/sitemap.xml

Please help

Comment: is it a page(cms)?i mean not product page.

Answer (score 3):

Please do not just copy the complete file to `app/code/local` (as mentioned in the other answer here). This is not upgrade safe and will cause some extra work when upgrading.

It's better to create a seperate module for this, for example `YourNamespache_Sitemap` with a proper rewrite of the model `Mage_Sitemap_Model_Sitemap` there.

In your `config.xml` put the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <YourNamespache_Sitemap>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </YourNamespache_Sitemap>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <yournamespace_sitemap>
                <class>YourNamespache_Sitemap_Model</class>
            </yournamespace_sitemap>
            <sitemap>
                <rewrite>
                    <sitemap>YourNamespache_Sitemap_Model_Sitemap</sitemap>
                </rewrite>
            </sitemap>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

And in `app/code/[local/community]/YourNamespace/Sitemap/Model` create the class `Sitemap.php` which extends the original sitemap model class. You only need to copy and adjust the `generateXml()` method in there, the rest can stay in the parent class.

```
class YourNamespace_Sitemap_Model_Sitemap extends Mage_Sitemap_Model_Sitemap {

    /**
     * Generate XML file
     *
     * @return Mage_Sitemap_Model_Sitemap
     */
    public function generateXml()
    {
        //copied and adjusted code from the parent generateXml method
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First copy file from `app\code\core\Mage\Sitemap\Model\Sitemap.php` to `app\code\local\Mage\Sitemap\Model\Sitemap.php`
and after add bellow code at line number : `201`

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter('identifier',array('neq'=>'coupon-partners'));
```

OR

Find bellow code in `generateXml()` function

```
$changefreq = (string)Mage::getStoreConfig('sitemap/page/changefreq', $storeId);
$priority   = (string)Mage::getStoreConfig('sitemap/page/priority', $storeId);
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sitemap/cms_page')->getCollection($storeId);
```

And replace this code:

```
$changefreq = (string)Mage::getStoreConfig('sitemap/page/changefreq', $storeId);
$priority   = (string)Mage::getStoreConfig('sitemap/page/priority', $storeId);
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sitemap/cms_page')->getCollection($storeId);
$collection->addFieldToFilter('identifier',array('neq'=>'coupon-partners'));
```

Tyr to generate sitemap again to admin side...

Comment: Copying files to app/code/local should be avoided whenever possible. It's better to create a rewrite.

Comment: This does not work because Mage::getResourceModel('sitemap/cms_page')->getCollection($storeId) produces an array, not an object, addFieldToFilter only works on objects